# Removing row from data frame when element in a column does not meet criteria

Tags: r, excel

I am new to R and am trying to figure out a way to, for the following data frame

| contact | status |
| --- | --- |
| 654 | Hello |
| 456 | Goodbye |
| 645 | John |
| 677 | Goodbye |

remove the row (645       John) so the output would be

| contact | status |
| --- | --- |
| 654 | Hello |
| 456 | Goodbye |
| 677 | Goodbye |

Below is what I have and I keep getting the error: Error in -c(i) : invalid argument to unary operator

```
for (i in CL [,"status"]) {
  if (i != "Hello"|| i!= "Goodbye") {
    CL <- CL[-c(i)]
  }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Try `CL[CL$status %in% c("Hello", "Goodbye"),]`

Answer (score 0):

you may try the below

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(!(contact==645 & status=='John'))
```

base r

```r
df[!(df$contact==645 & df$status=='John'),]
```